# PHP: Can't find my database

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I'm having problems connecting to my database

```
<?php

@mysqli_connect( "127.0.0.1", "root", "root" ) or die( "Cannot connect to the database!" );
@mysqli_select_db( "phpherexamen" ) or die( "Connected to the database, but there's nothing here!" );
session_start();

?>
```

This is the code I'm using to connect too my bd, but i always get the message:

> Connected to the database, but there's nothing here!

My db looks like this[image]

What am I not seeing? :)

Comment: Is that table a valid name? (As in, are they allowed to have spaces?)

Comment: @Lee If you're referring to "Nieuwe tabel aanmaken" ... that just means "make new table" in Dutch, it's not actually a table name :P

Comment: You really ought to stop suppressing error messages. Otherwise you will get a blank face when you meet a blank page (with no errors). Add some error handling and logging instead and fail gracefully :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the result of mysqli_connect function as a second parameter of the mysql_select_db function.

```
$link = mysqli_connect( "127.0.0.1", "root", "root" )
if (!$link) {
    die("Cannot connect to the database!");
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('phpherexamen', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ("Connected to the database, but there's nothing here!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With procedural style `mysqli` you need to pass `mysqli_select_db` an instance of `mysqli`

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "root");
mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "phpherexamen");
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the connection in a variable, and then pass that to the select_db command.

```
$db = mysqli_connect(...);
mysqli_select_db($db, 'phpherexamen');
```

Answer (score 0):

Wether you use the object oriented style:

```
$handle = @mysqli_connect( "127.0.0.1", "root", "root" ) or die( "Cannot connect to the database!" );
$handle->mysqli_select_db( "phpherexamen" ) or die( "Connected to the database, but there's nothing here!" );
```

or the procedural style:

```
$handle = @mysqli_connect( "127.0.0.1", "root", "root" ) or die( "Cannot connect to the database!" );
    @$mysqli_select_db($handle, "phpherexamen" ) or die( "Connected to the database, but there's nothing here!" );
```

but Mysqli requires an object to know which connection the mysql select db should apply to.

Sidenote: The old extension MySQL that was replaced by MySQLi supported to cache the last connection so you didnt need to specify the database handle but this is a great error-magnet if you have a website using multiple connections or want to fire a query while looping a result or similar thatswhy this only works with a valid handle or better said object which is alot more sane then the other, old method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, appreciated!